# print result of GROUP_CONCAT in java

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I want to print the result of mysql `GROUP_CONCAT` in java and it return blob.

But when I do `resultset.getBlob("columnname")` its throwing sql exception. so how to go about it

or I need to `resultset.getBytes("columnname");`

Comment: Can you provide exception stacktrace?

Comment: getstring also throws exception, also stacktrace is not clear only showing sqlexception..

Comment: Are you able to get the values resulted in group_concat?

Comment: can anyone answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

Using getBytes: You can use getBytes to retrieve the BLOB data and then convert it to a string before printing it.

This is an example:

```
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(columnname) AS concatenated FROM your_table");
if (resultSet.next()) {
    Blob blob = resultSet.getBlob("concatenated");
    if (blob != null) {
        byte[] bytes = blob.getBytes(1, (int) blob.length());
        String concatenatedString = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
        System.out.println(concatenatedString);
    }
}
```